# SELENIUM 3.4 NOT OPENING FIREFOX WITH GEKODRIVER V-9

Tags: selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Using geckodriver v.09,jdk 1.8,selenium-java-3.4.0,selenium-server-standalone-3.4,downloaded two mozilla firefox 46 and 53.but in control panel-->program folder only able to see mozilla firefox 53 version.Getting error for below code.

Comment: use a newer geckodriver version like 0.16

Answer (score 0):

`geckodriver` v0.9.0 was released in July 2016. So last year. In the meantime, several Firefox versions were released, so most likely your `geckodriver` version is way too old to be able to work with Firefox 53.

One way to solve this is to update to the latest version of geckodriver, meaning v0.16.1. One note though, for v0.16.0 it's mentioned that you need Selenium 3.4.
You can see more [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

To answer the other question, regarding the Firefox version, this is what I'm doing to make it possible:

1. Install any FF version (even the latest one) and make sure you uncheck Maintenance Service (or something similar it's called)
2. Go to FF Options and disable the automatic updates
3. Uninstall Firefox (using the default options, without manually deleting anything)
4. Install the version that you need

Otherwise, even if you install an older version, it will automatically try to update and at the next restart it will be the latest version.